# Bootstrap 3 carousels customization ala hulu or itunes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

IMO the bootstrap carousel out of the box is limited and not designed for enterprise use.  Does anyone know of a resource out there with customization of the component to work similar to how Hulu, netflix and itunes have implemented carousels on their sites?

More specifically, i need the carousel to not overflow onto multiple rows and instead stay on one line and reveal only the amount of items that the space provides. The new grid system in BS3 works great for this sans carousel, however as soon as you apply the carousel functionality it behaves likes the old bootstrap and doesn't work well at the smaller breakpoints.

see netflix.com or hulu.com or take a look at the itunes desktop app for examples of desired implementation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a site for offering contract work.

Comment: Do you mean something like this bootstrap example? It looks very similar to the http://www.hulu.com/ you posted.

Comment: Hi @Will - What example? I dont see a link.

Comment: @Gordon - It IS on topic. I was just offering a thank you for anyone to answer.

Comment: @JeffSherwood Well, yeah, don't do that again. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=money. Since you removed that part, I am reopening the question. However, note that questions asking for libraries are off topic, too and the whole thing still sounds like "write that code for me". Consider going through http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist to improve the question.

Comment: @will, can you please post the link again? Im not seeing it. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the 'slide' section of the carousel to include any kind of content including fluid rows and thumbnails.

http://jsfiddle.net/fVqJ3/

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

<div class="item active">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" /></a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" /></a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" /></a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" /></a></div>
</div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/carousel.html) example? 
It looks very similar to the http://www.hulu.com/ you posted.